# Why is the stabilization of augmented $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-algebras equivalent to $k$-module spectra?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra

(I have already asked this [on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006620/why-is-the-stabilization-of-augmented-mathbbe-infty-algebras-equivalent-to), but it didn't draw much attention there, so I am reposting it here.)

Example 1.1.4 of Jacob Lurie's [DAGX](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/DAG-X.pdf) says that the stabilization $\operatorname{Stab}((\mathrm{CAlg}_k)_{/k})$ of the $\infty$-category of augmented $\mathbb{E}_\infty$ algebras over $k$ can be identified with the $\infty$-category of $k$-module spectra $\mathrm{Mod}_k$.

The reference mentioned there is Theorem 7.3.5.14 of Lurie's [Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf). However, there is no Theorem 7.3.5.14 in (the current version of) Higher Algebra, and *Lemma* 7.3.5.14 is just a characterization of idempotent morphisms, so I don't think that the above identification would follow from it.

I suspect that the relevant theorem got renumbered since the writing of DAGX. Could someone point to a reference for this fact (or sketch the proof)?

Comment: HA.7.3.4.14 (so it was either renumbering or a typo)